# How to make fragment pick the portrait view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

My app for phones has a pager with the main view and the premium features view when swiping right, in landscape mode it has a slightly modified version to fit the landscape orientation.

Now i have to make the tablet UI, and I'd like to show both views on one screen, I've already managed to show them, but the tablet in landscape mode is picking up the fragments from layout-land instead of the portrait layout, and I need it to pick the portrait ones to show side by side.

How can i make the fragment pick the portrait version even if the tablet is in landscape without creating duplicate layouts?

My fragments look like this

```
public class PremiumFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup premiumView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.premium_features, container, false);
        return premiumView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onView created ran");
        Intent intent = new Intent("setup");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getBaseContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while but for anyone interested in this matter:

If I understand correctly, you need to have a portrait layout, a landscape layout (for mobile for example) and a different landscape layout for tablets which matches the portrait one. There's not that much duplicity involved. You can include an independent non-qualified layout in your qualified layouts.

Lets say you have these layouts:

```
layout-land/my_fragment.xml
layout-port/my_fragment.xml
layout-large-land/my_fragment.xml
layout/my_fragment_content.xml
```

layout-port/my_fragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include
        layout="@layout/my_fragment_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout >
```

layout-land/my_fragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   //something completely different

</FrameLayout >
```

and layout-large-land/my_fragment.xml (contents are the same as portrait one):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        layout="@layout/my_fragment_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout >
```

There is some minimum duplicity involved but the only important thing is that you have no reason to ever touch `layout-port/my_fragment.xml` or `layout-large-land/my_fragment.xml` because all vital information is contained in a single file `layout/my_fragment_content.xml`.

This topic is more thoroughly analysed in this article that the author probably read aleady:

[Android Developers: Building a Flexible UI](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html)